# Invalid permissions for spanner during mvn test in travis

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, travis-ci, google-cloud-spanner

Has anyone come across a way to run google spanner maven tests (creating and deleted databases), I always get invalid permissions. These test are being run as a service account owner that has been confirmed to run locally.

When running travis in debug mode you can confirm that the correct service account has been activated.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very specific, but it is certainly possible. I run integration tests on Travis CI for my open source JDBC driver. The source code including Travis configuration file can be found here: https://github.com/olavloite/spanner-jdbc

In order to run tests on Travis, you need to make sure that Travis can authenticate against Google. For this you need:

1. The key file (.json) that was generated by Google when you created your service account must be accessible to Travis. You do not want to include your key file in plain text in your repository, so you should encrypt it (see https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files/).
2. Add the encrypted file to your repository.
3. Add a decrypt command to the before_install part of your Travis file:

`before_install:
    - openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_aabbccddeeff_key -iv $encrypted_aabbccddeeff_iv
      -in cloudspanner-key.json.enc -out cloudspanner-key.json -d`

4. Make sure your test code picks up the decrypted file for authentication (in this example that is the file 'cloudspanner-key.json'.

In order to make your code pick up the decrypted file, you should pass the json file explicitly to Google instead of setting it as an environment variable:

```
Builder builder = SpannerOptions.newBuilder();
builder.setCredentials(getCredentialsFromFile(credentialsPath));
...

public static GoogleCredentials getCredentialsFromFile(String credentialsPath) throws IOException
    {
        if (credentialsPath == null || credentialsPath.length() == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("credentialsPath may not be null or empty");
        GoogleCredentials credentials = null;
        File credentialsFile = new File(credentialsPath);
        if (!credentialsFile.isFile())
        {
            throw new IOException(
                    String.format("Error reading credential file %s: File does not exist", credentialsPath));
        }
        try (InputStream credentialsStream = new FileInputStream(credentialsFile))
        {
            credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(credentialsStream, CloudSpannerOAuthUtil.HTTP_TRANSPORT_FACTORY);
        }
        return credentials;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to reword it, for doing crud operations via the google-cloud project, having the json file set as an environment variable works correctly, when attempting to create a new database the permissions  don't seem to get picked up from IAM

Comment: It's probably easier if you pass the credentials file explicitly in your code to Google, instead of setting it in an environment variable. I've added a code example on how to do that in the above answer.

Comment: It's looking like a change when you go up to google-cloud 0.26, appreciate your help